# Failed to render and update auto layout status

Tags: swift, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode8, size-classes

Since few days ago I'm getting this error and I'm completely stuck on my project.

This is just a `Runtime` issue, I can run my project but can't touch interface builder at all.

Didn't change anything on `IB` to start this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: bundleIdentifier != nil'
```

My bundle identifier is not nil.

Here is my log file

```
Process:               IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch [10742]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch
Identifier:            IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch
Version:               8.1 (11524)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [8117]
Responsible:           IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch [10742]
User ID:               501


Date/Time:             2016-11-11 18:10:08.256 -0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2657)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        544DA3C3-CD64-6444-0CE0-06F48A5B5FE9




Time Awake Since Boot: 9000 seconds


System Integrity Protection: enabled


Crashed Thread:        0


Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY


Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: bundleIdentifier != nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 307.14.2 - Device: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x - Runtime: iOS 10.1 (14B72) - DeviceType: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x


Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010963134b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108faa21e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109635442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x0000000108b40e4d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   UserNotifications                   0x000000010f48bac9 -[UNUserNotificationCenter initWithBundleIdentifier:] + 210
5   UserNotifications                   0x000000010f48b773 __53+[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]_block_invoke + 106
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e412e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cee12 dispatch_once_f + 68
8   UserNotifications                   0x000000010f48b706 +[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] + 45
9   T-Rex                               0x000000021f78c6ef +[OneSignalHelper registerAsUNNotificationCenterDelegate] + 63
10  T-Rex                               0x000000021f7a0c62 +[UIApplication(Swizzling) load] + 450
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108fac0f9 call_load_methods + 246
12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108facda3 load_images + 70
13  ???                                 0x0000000105b6fc5e 0x0 + 4390845534
14  ???                                 0x0000000105b7b0aa 0x0 + 4390891690
15  ???                                 0x0000000105b7a23a 0x0 + 4390887994
16  ???                                 0x0000000105b7a2cf 0x0 + 4390888143
17  ???                                 0x0000000105b729eb 0x0 + 4390857195
18  ???                                 0x0000000105b76c20 0x0 + 4390874144
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b82aea4 dlopen + 59
20  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086fe0b6 -[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderTool _resultByLoadingUnloadedBundleInstance:] + 154
21  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086fe73b -[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderTool loadBuiltLiveViewBundleInstances:] + 793
22  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086f904c __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke + 351
23  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086f8e27 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:] + 442
24  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086f8853 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke + 125
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e412e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cc7a5 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 315
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e412e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cb52d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1054
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095f54f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095baf8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095ba494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
32  Foundation                          0x0000000108a8cff0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
33  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086c4528 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 459
34  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086c46df -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 117
35  IBFoundation                        0x00000001086c5257 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1189
36  IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch        0x0000000105b69be7 main + 34
37  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b82d68d start + 1


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb5bdda __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000010b8d5fd7 abort + 129
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000000010ac5c95a abort_message + 266
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000000010ac81cff default_terminate_handler() + 267
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108faa49f _objc_terminate() + 103
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000000010ac7ee69 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000000010ac7eee3 std::terminate() + 51
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e4142 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cee12 dispatch_once_f + 68
9   com.apple.UserNotifications         0x000000010f48b706 +[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] + 45
10  io.t-rex.iosapp                     0x000000021f78c6ef +[OneSignalHelper registerAsUNNotificationCenterDelegate] + 63 (OneSignalHelper.m:540)
11  io.t-rex.iosapp                     0x000000021f7a0c62 +[UIApplication(Swizzling) load] + 450 (OneSignal.m:1311)
12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108fac0f9 call_load_methods + 246
13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108facda3 load_images + 70
14  dyld_sim                            0x0000000105b6fc5e dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList*) + 439
15  dyld_sim                            0x0000000105b7b0aa ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 320
16  dyld_sim                            0x0000000105b7a23a ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 138
17  dyld_sim                            0x0000000105b7a2cf ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 75
18  dyld_sim                            0x0000000105b729eb dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 87
19  dyld_sim                            0x0000000105b76c20 dlopen + 852
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b82aea4 dlopen + 59
21  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086fe0b6 -[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderTool _resultByLoadingUnloadedBundleInstance:] + 154
22  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086fe73b -[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderTool loadBuiltLiveViewBundleInstances:] + 793
23  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086f904c __80-[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:]_block_invoke + 351
24  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086f8e27 -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:] + 442
25  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086f8853 __88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke + 125
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e412e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cc7a5 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 315
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e412e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cb52d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1054
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00000001095f54f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00000001095baf8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00000001095ba494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
33  com.apple.Foundation                0x0000000108a8cff0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
34  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086c4528 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 459
35  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086c46df -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 117
36  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086c5257 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1189
37  IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch        0x0000000105b69be7 main + 34
38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b82d68d start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb5ce5e kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7d2a85 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 248
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7d2887 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb5d2de read + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation                0x0000000108b22c29 -[NSConcreteFileHandle readDataOfLength:] + 498
2   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086c4342 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool _WAIT_FOR_PARENT_TO_EXIT:] + 30
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7c2810 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7e412e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7ca24c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 809
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cba0e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 506
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cb7b4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90736 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90211 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb5c4e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90211 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb54456 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7ceaaa _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 16
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b7cc4e5 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 353
3   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086f84ef -[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:] + 1381
4   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation           0x00000001086c410e -[IBAbstractPlatformTool runMessageChannel:] + 129
5   com.apple.Foundation                0x0000000108a9cee4 __NSThread__start__ + 1243
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90aab _pthread_body + 180
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb909f7 _pthread_start + 286
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90221 thread_start + 13


Thread 5:: NetworkLoad
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb5441a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb53867 mach_msg + 55


2   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00000001095bb7b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00000001095bac31 __CFRunLoopRun + 1345
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00000001095ba494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.GeoServices               0x000000011ab484f7 _runNetworkThread + 445
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90aab _pthread_body + 180
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb909f7 _pthread_start + 286
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90221 thread_start + 13


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000010bb5c4e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bb90211 start_wqthread + 13
```

This is a fresh install of my entire computer.

Comment: Are you using an IBDesignable/IBInspectable component that reaches out to `UNUserNotificationCenter`? The stacktrace indicates this, if it's true you might want to remove the reference to `UNUserNotificationCenter`